# How to fetch rows based on foreign key NULL criteria?

Tags: sql-server

I have tables `AccountOpeningDetails`, `Customer`, `Supplier`. The `AccountOpeningDetails` table contains `FKCustomerID` and `FKSupplierID`.

The sample record can be seen below:

```
FKCustomerID        FKSupplierID          Particulars           Debit           Credit
26                  NULL                  Test1                 6000.00         NULL
NULL                15                    Test2                 NULL            8000.00
```

I want to get corresponding name of Customer AND Supplier in both the records means the output should be something like below:

```
FKCustomerID    CustomerName      FKSupplierID     SupplierName         Particulars        
26              UserA             NULL                                  Test1                 
NULL                              15               UserB                Test2
```

As seen above the when there is `FKCustomerID` present the `CustomerName` should appear and since `FKSupplierID` is null there should be no name in `SupplierName` and vice versa.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
   aod.FKCustomerID, aod.FKSupplierID, aod.Particulars, aod.Debit, aod.Credit 
FROM 
   AccountOpeningDetails aod    
WHERE 
   aod.FKAccountOpeningID = (SELECT ID FROM AccountOpening WHERE VoucherNo = '1')
```

What to modify in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to show once the customer, once the supplier, based on whether the FK is null or not, you need to use two `LEFT OUTER JOIN` constructs:

```
SELECT 
   aod.FKCustomerID, c.CustomerName, aod.FKSupplierID, s.SupplierName,
   aod.Particulars, aod.Debit, aod.Credit 
FROM 
   dbo.AccountOpeningDetails aod    
INNER JOIN
   dbo.AccountOpening ao ON aod.FKAccountOpeningID = ao.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.Customer c ON aod.FKCustomerID = c.CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.Supplier s ON aod.FKSupplierID = s.SupplierID
WHERE 
   ao.VoucherNo = '1'
```

I also "merged" that messy `WHERE` condition you had into an  `INNER JOiN` on the `AccountOpening` table.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm :-)

Comment: Is there a way without using outer join? Means the whole query in just one line?

Comment: @user2738231: no there is no way to write this in a single line - you do need the JOINs - no way around that